# How to fix not working Jquery on a html page, that was dynamically loaded into a div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm loading a html file into my index.php by using jQuery.

```
$("#load").click(function() {
   $("#content").load("/content/page.html");
});
```

The page.html content:

```
<img class="img" src="https://www.nzxt.com/uploads/download/attachment/117/Phantom-530-wallpaper-1920x1080-3.jpg"><br/>
<p style="color:green">test.html Success 1</p>
```

I have also a function that changes the size of the image when the window width changes, problem is, when the page loads... the image is shown in 1920x1080px, but it should be 80% of window width.

```
  function img_resize(ww,wh) {
    $(".img").css("width", ww);
      var img_w = $(".img").width();
    $(".img").css("margin", wh);
  };
```

So after clicking the button, the `page.html` loads into the `index.php div`, the image shows in 1920x1080px resolution, when i resize the browser window, the image shrinks to 80% of window width and can't use css width:80%; for it, because it has other functions that define the size (pixels) of the image, that's just calculation. But the code above `img_resize(ww,wh)` is setting/adding the width to the image.
I tried with mousemove, mouseover and onload, nothing worked.

```
<img class="img" src="https://www.nzxt.com/uploads/download/attachment/117/Phantom-530-wallpaper-1920x1080-3.jpg" onload="img_resize()"><br/>
<p style="color:green">test.html Success 1</p>
```

How can i "start" the `img_resize()` function when the `page.html` file is loaded?

Comment: try `$(".img").css('width','80');`  but in your `onload="img_resize()"` function no perameter you have pass `function img_resize(ww,wh)` so where its come from when function call

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

```
$("#load").click(function() {
   $("#content").load("/content/page.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
     if ( status != "error" ) {
       img_resize(ww,wh);
     }
   });
});
```

Remeber to supply `ww` and `wh` parameters as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <img class="img" 
         src="https://www.nzxt.com/uploads/download/attachment/117/Phantom-
         530-wallpaper-1920x1080-3.jpg" style="width: 80%;"><br/>
```

try this working for me!

Comment: Thx mate but I know CSS :) It's not what I'm looking for.